# How to get 2 values with recursion?

Tags: python

Im trying to build a code that will print all the binary sequences
for example,

```
n=2
output:
00
01
10
11
```

My logic is to add '0' to the first half of the outputs in the start and add '1' to the other half and so on.
but I'm facing trouble in returning 2 values with recursion
This is what I've tried writing:

```
def binary(prefix='',n):
    if n==0:
        return prefix    
    else:
        for i in range(2):
            if i==0:
                return ('0'+binary(prefix,n-1))
            if i==1:
                return ('1'+binary(prefix,n-1))
```

Comment: HINT: `return x,y` will return `x` and `y` as `tuple`

Comment: Your logic has a huge flaw: the `i==1` condition is *never* reached because the first `i==0` is always run and will always return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
def print_binary(prefix,n):
if n==0:
    print (prefix)
else:
    print_binary((prefix+'0'),n-1)
    print_binary((prefix+'1'),n-1)
```

Comment: @roi.shtiv Huh! you posted this answer in the previous edit to the question didn't you.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a generator:

```
def binary(n):
    if n==0:
        yield ''
    else:
        for i in range(2):
            for item in binary(n-1):
                yield ('0' if i==0 else '1')+item

list(binary(3))  # ['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']
```

Note: I removed the *prefix*, as your code was returning a postfix. Add a wrapper function if you need that functionality.

You can also use the itertools module:

```
[''.join(item) for item in itertools.product(*['01' for _ in range(n)])]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably what you want to do:

```
def recursive_get_bin_str(s, n):
    if n == 0:
        print s
    else:
        for digit in '01':
            recursive_get_bin_str(s + digit, n - 1)
```

Recursion that uses return won't work since then function will return only one value and you need multiple values. If you try to return multiple value you will have to use some kind of iterable (tuple, list, deque). Example with deque:

```
from collections import deque

def linear_get_bin_str(n):
    bin_strings = deque([''])
    for i in xrange(n):
        while len(bin_strings[0]) == i:
            bin_str = bin_strings.popleft()
            for digit in '01':
                bin_strings.append(bin_str + digit)
    return bin_strings
```

Answer (score 2):

This function will generate strings for n>0 where instead of a prefix what you needed probably was a list.

```
def binary(n,li=["0","1"]):
    if n==0:
        return []
    elif n==1:
        return li
    lis=[j+i for i in li for j in ["0","1"]]
    return binary(n-1,lis)
```

binary(2) : `['00', '10', '01', '11']`

binary(3) : `['000', '100', '010', '110', '001', '101', '011', '111']`

Answer (score 1):

you may use `itertools`:

```
from itertools import product, repeat

for i in product(*repeat('01', n)):
    print(''.join(i))
```

then your function will look something like:

```
def binary(n):
   return [''.join(comb) for comb in product(*repeat('01', n))]
```

Comment: Hmm...then if the input is `2`, the output will be `['00', '01', '11']`. OP seems also need `'10'`.